# Howto read currentpage after index.php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'd like to have some help with my code, setting keywords, description and title of the page.

My head.php (included in the index.php):

```
<?php 
$current = $SERVER_[REQUEST_URI];
$home = "/#!/page_HOME";
if($current==$home) {
  $title = "Example.com || Home";
  $keywords = "some words";
  $description = "description text";
}   
?>
```

My websites uses 'strange' URL, like: `http://example.com/index.php#!/page_HOME` .
Is is a webpage with CSS and jQuery tricks to load the different pages.

Now I'd like to change the keywords, description and title of the page by clicking on the menu link.

In the index.php the menu and include statements are like this:

```
**link in menu:** 
<a href="#!/page_HOME">Home</a>
**include in webpage:** 
<li id="page_HOME">
    <a href="#!/page_SPLASH" class="close"></a>  
    <?php include('home.html'); ?>
</li>
```

I've tried to do this with `$SERVER_[REQUEST_URI]` and so on, but I can't manage.

Please help solving this 'problem'

Comment: I am not sure if $SERVER_[REQUEST_URI] (which should be $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; anyway) will take care of what you are trying to do. I think in your URL case you might be better off using regex checking.

Comment: It looks like you are using JavaScript to go to different pages by the looks of your URL. Is that correct?

Comment: indeed. And I think that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the anchor fragment (everything after #) by using `parse_url()`; see: http://php.net/parse_url

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlFragment = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT );

switch( $urlFragment )
{
    case '!/page_SPLASH':
        $title = "Example.com || Splash";
        $keywords = "splash content";
        $description = "splash description text";
        break;

    /* define more pages here */

    case '!/page_HOME': /* no break; intended */
    default:
        $title = "Example.com || Home";
        $keywords = "some words";
        $description = "description text";
        break;
}
```

Comment: YES! Great great help!

Comment: just print out `$urlFragment` (`var_dump( $urlFragment );`) before the switch to check it's content…

Comment: If I use the following code, nothing appears:
<?php echo $urlFragment; ?>

Comment: checked. If I use case '':  it will give me that default info.
So.. It empty and stays empty.. why? :)

Comment: ??  Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Roy Why don't you just take a look at some PHP routing system, as this is what you are trying to implement. For example: http://www.slimframework.com/ or http://joltframework.com/