# Keywords & Description with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a website which loads pages with Jquery. The code is like this:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlFragment = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT );

switch( $urlFragment )
{
    case '!/page_SPLASH':
        $title = "Example.com || Splash";
        $keywords = "splash content";
        $description = "splash description text";
        break;

    /*  more pages here */

    case '!/page_HOME': /* no break; intended */
    default:
        $title = "Example.com || Home";
        $keywords = "some words";
        $description = "description text";
        break;

    case '!/page_ABOUT': /* no break; intended */
    default:
        $title = "Example.com || Home";
        $keywords = "some words";
        $description = "description text";
        break;
}
```

If I switch to other pages, the title, keywords and description won't change. So, also Google won't 'see' the other pages's t, k & d.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are loading the pages with AJAX? Than changing keywords or any other meta tags won't do anything to let Google 'see' that.

Comment: No I just use Jquery to load the pages..
So it is 1 page with different content.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by making your ajax pages crawlable. Google released a [specification for doing that](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

This is a multi-step process. The short version is:

1. Use Google's special form of fragment identifier when identifying your "pages" that are loaded via ajax. That special form is `#!` rather than just `#`, e.g. `http://example.com#!about` for the "about" page and `http://example.com#!contact` for the "contact" page.
2. Respond to requests for `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about`, `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=contact`, etc., with the complete page containing the relevant fragment. This is what the bot will request (since fragment identifiers aren't sent to servers, they convert it into a query string parameter).
3. Optionally update your site map to include the ajax-enabled URLs.

Comment: I though I was a nerd ;) haha!
And I forgot to add the last thread about this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787984/howto-read-currentpage-after-index-php

Comment: I meam.. I don't understand ;)

Comment: @Roy: You'll have to have a read through the specification (assuming you want to support Google's crawlable ajax stuff).

Comment: Ok get the idea now, about the snapshot.
But, I really don't understand how to use the HtmlUnit in my website, wich files I need, etc.

Comment: @Roy: HtmlUnit is just one example of something they say you *might* use server-side to produce your snapshots. You can use anything you like (or produce them manually).

Comment: I understand. There are more examples in the thread. But still.. if I want to use the HtmlUnit example. Wich file do I have to download to add and edit?